# STM32 - Serial Audio Interface (SAI) - dual data line transmit possible?

Tags: audio, stm32, dac, i2s

I’m working on a USB sound interface, using a STM32F7 and an external DAC chip offering 8 stereo output channels.

Most of the DAC are offering multiple serial data inputs ports. For example, the Analog Device ADAU1966A is offering 8x data lines inputs. That’s great to lower the clock speed.

On the STM32F7, each SAI drivers has two blocs, SAI_A and SAI_B, so two serial data outputs that I can use to transfert the audio data to the DAC.

Image of the envisaged communication:

[image]

I have 2 questions:

- Am I right to suppose that I can use SD_A and SD_B in parallel to send audio data to the DAC? (I can configure this DAC to use only DSDATA1 and DSDATA2 to control OUT1 … OUT16)
- It’s a shame that I can’t have more serial data outputs on the STM32. A lot of high end DACs have multiple serial data inputs, and can work at 32-bit and 192kHz and more. Maybe I miss something? Do you have an idea on how to get the best out of this SAI transmission?

Thanks a lot, have a nice day!
Jean

Comment: There is no software question here . Post it to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do not post links to images

Comment: From my limited understanding of STM32 I2S this is not possible. They are completely independent units.